# Why does Azure Service Bus average 1,500 "requests" per hour without any business client publications?

Tags: azureservicebus

My Azure portal shows that my Service Bus is averaging 1,500 "requests" per hour without any business clients publishing to it.

Note:

1. I deployed an Azure Function app thinking that the traffic on the remote instance would model my local instance.
2. I also disabled Application Insights and observed no significant difference.

[image]

Comment: If Functions is using the management API (HTTP) to periodically check for queue length, those checks will generate those requests.

Comment: Is there an alternative API one can employ so that they do not get billed for idle Functions?

Comment: How would you? You don't trigger or scale Functions yourself, Functions host and scale controller do.